# preg_match not returning anything

Tags: php, regex

Please assist with the following:

I use the following regex pattern to catch all values inside MySQL queries `(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1`  This works perfectly fine when run on regex online tester https://regex101.com/r/tysxYk/1

But when i use it inside php it returns nothing and can't figure out what's wrong

```
<?php
    
$query = <<<EOT
    UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'a:1151:{s:15:\"activ";}' WHERE `option_name` = 'my_options';

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 'Stavanger', '4006', 'Norway');
EOT;
    
$status = preg_match( '#(["\'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1#', $query, $matches );
print_r($matches);
```

Thanks for your support !

Comment: I think you should double the backslashes, see the regex101 generated code here https://regex101.com/r/tysxYk/1/codegen?language=php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex101 has it's own code-generator, using the provided link, that will generate:

```
<?php
$re = '/(["\'])(?:(?=(\\\\?))\2.)*?\1/m';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

1. Regex Flags (Optionally)
2. `preg_match_all` instead off `preg_match`

Comment: There's no need for the `m` flag if the regexp doesn't contain `^` or `$` anchors.

Comment: Thank you for note about code generator. Didn't knew about it.